# is there a way to change all Text view's Text color attribute inside a Grid layout in android studio?

Tags: android, textview

I have a `grid layout` and some text view inside it. I would like to know if there is a simple way to change all `text view's` attributes simultaneous. i.e some way like `CSS` in web design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the style property of each TextView to a shared style resource you've defined. For instance:

**Custom style:**

Styles can be applied to a particular view. Child views do not inherit the styling.

styles.xml:

```
<style name="MyStyle" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/indigo_text</item>
</style>
```

MyView.xml:

```
<TextView style="@style/MyStyle" ... />
```

**Custom theme:**

Themes are settings that can be applied to the entire app or to a particular view and all of its descendants.

themes.xml:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/indigo_text</item>
</style>
```

MyView.xml:

```
<FrameLayout android:theme="@style/MyTheme" ... />
```

Or to theme the entire app, update the application definition in the Manifest file:

```
<application android:theme="@style/MyTheme"  ... />
```

More on themes: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/theme-editor

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i want omit adding attribute to each text view,otherwise, this was a simpler way :  android:textColor="@color/indigo_text"

Comment: In that case, create a theme and set the `android:theme` attribute on the outermost view or the entire application.

Comment: Nice guide, Thank you!